# Spring Data JPA native query result entity

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My native join query produces a new result that is a combination of database tables, so I created a dto for that resulting object (will be a list of records on a screen).

I believe I need to make it an entity, so JPA can recognize it, would that be the best way to do it?

Also, the entity needs an id, and I was hoping to let jpa generate it auto, but I'm getting "Invalid parameter: Unknown column name id. ERRORCODE=-4460, SQLSTATE=null"

My result set contains 4 of the same records instead of 4 different, and I think it has to do with my id field not set properly

Any help would be appreciated on the subject, thanks.

`public interface ErrorCodeRepo extends JpaRepository<Errors, ErrorsPK> {

```
@Query("SELECT e.transDate, e.category FROM Errors e")            
List<QueuedErrors> findQueuedErrors();
```

}`

DTO class:
`
public class QueuedErrors {

```
private String transDate;
private String category;

public QueuedErrors(String transDate, String category) {
    this.transDate = transDate;
    this.category = category;
}

public String getTransDate() {
    return transDate;
}
public void setTransDate(String transDate) {
    this.transDate = transDate;
}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create navite query which contains results from multiple tables (after joins) you don't have to create new entities.

Better way to solve this problem is to projection with interface or class DTO.
For example, if you want to combine results from Person and Address Entities, simply create interface:

```
public interface PersonView {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
    String getStreet();
}
```

You can see combined fileds from Person (firstName, lastName) and Address (street).
You have to use it as query response, like this:

```
@Query(...)
List<PersonView> getPersonWithStreet(String state);
```

You can read more about it here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Ok, I did it once with the interface in the repo, but I didn't like my result being part of the repo...so I'll like to do the projection with a class DTO.  I've created a dto class, but I'm missing how to tie it to the repo, I get the ConverterNotFoundException

Comment: Can you provide dto class and repository code? 
And you don't have to create interface with response inside repository interface.

Comment: I added the DTO and the repo above...I tried returning Object[][] and then loop through that, which works, but would like to do it an easier way, thanks.

Comment: I've simplified my query to test a few things, I'm able to populate the DTO when I use a constructor expression in the query, but without the Constructor expression, I believe I need to match the parameters of the entity class(es).

Comment: using my native query with 3 tables might be more difficult, will it even know about my entities?  I don't even have an entity created for one of the tables...I'll experiment with one table that has an entity first and see if i can match the parms, and what happens when I make it a native query.

Comment: I've simplified my query above just so the complexity doesn't get in the way, but still after removing the Constructor expression i can't get it to work, even after matching parms in the DTO class, and entity(if that is needed too).

Comment: Alright, I figured it out the way you mentioned in the first place, with the Projection Interface, seems to work nicely, I just send back the interface...works nicely, just didn't understand it earlier...Thanks!